# AS3 how to can I get the URLRequest to repeat the action at set intervals

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5

I am running the AS3 below to load a ".txt" file to an Adobe Air desktop app message board built in Flash CS5. I have a timer set to run and repeat the process, basically to run back through the code again and it is firing off the NotificationType.Critical. even though there isn't a new file loaded.

How can I make it so the URLRequest repeats, let say every 120000 milliseconds to look for new file? If file is new load the file and notify user, if file isn't new just ignore?

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("https://my_text_file.txt"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loadedText:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    if(myText_txt.htmlText!=loadedText.data){
        myText_txt.htmlText = loadedText.data;
        mainWindow.notifyUser(NotificationType.CRITICAL) 
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

thanks new to AS3

Comment: Is the file online or is it a local file? It is possible to check the last time a local file was modified on a local file using `File.modificationDate`.

Comment: see my edited version for procedural use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var myInterval:uint  = setInterval (loadUrl, 120000);
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("https://my_text_file.txt"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
  var loadedText:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    if(myText_txt.htmlText!=loadedText.data){
       myText_txt.htmlText = loadedText.data;
       mainWindow.notifyUser(NotificationType.CRITICAL) 
    }else {
      //do nothing
    }
}

function loadUrl():void {
        loader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("https://my_text_file.txt"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
}
```

Comment: I had an error in my link, sorry, working now!! I will let you now if it fires off notification in a bit

Comment: well I have an issue again lol I will post all the code to a new question. it is making the NotificationType.Crytical go off everytime it looks for new file.